# VPN over Crappy ISP

Tags: cisco, vpn, isp, ssh

Like many folks, I have a crappy ISP. Every couple of minutes, my ISP will drop a handful of packets.

For "normal" activity such as web browsing, emailing, or even netflix, it works great; no one notices a few packets out of a thousand every 7-12 minutes.

I happen to work on a VPN over this connection, and invariable the VPN is not resistant to droppage of any packets. My ssh/rdp/whatever sessions get bounced quite frequently.

With tools such as mosh I can continue to function, but can get quite annoyed.

In addition, one of my company's offices also has an unreliable Internet connection and the L2L IPSEC tunnels seem very sensitive to that.

What's the best way to establish a VPN across an unreliable ISP?

*edit: I should mention I live in a rural area and exactly one "choice" for ISP

Comment: Get a new ISP.  Seriously, there's little you can do without spending a lot of money.  Cheaper to get more reliable service.

Comment: Rural 4g: $65/month
Full T1: $1750/month

Comment: If this is about home networking, that is off-topic here. You could try to ask on [su].

Comment: Suggestion, if you have a choice between tcp and udp as your transport, use udp. It can handle the dropped packet better since your client/server protocols will most likely use tcp and retransmit if needed.

Comment: All kidding aside, this is a general network engineering question. Knowing that you have to deal with the reality that ISPs must and will drop packets occasionally, how can we ease the discomfort of end users by eliminating connection resets?

Comment: this stack handles Qs from people a) working in professional networking contexts and b) Qs about networks over which they have control. This belongs in Super User.